# Monitoring tool for Sphinx search server

Tags: php, sphinx

I am new to Sphinx and looking for monitoring tool to verify my indexes.

I came to know this tool from the following blog post but there is no option for self-hosting the tool in my own server.

http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2015/01/31/sphinx-tools-beta-simplifying-sphinx-administration-monitoring/

https://tools.sphinxsearch.com/user/login

I had a little experience on Elastic search Head plugin. It was really awesome. 
https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head

I am looking like the same for Sphinx. Any idea would be appreciated ? thank you!!

Comment: Its not a 'monitoring' tool, but I made this http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/phpsphinxadmin.phps - it a lightweight 'frontend' to a sphinx instance. Sort of modelled after phpmyadmin, and can certainly be used to manually 'verify' indexes.

Comment: @barryhunter, thank you for the reply. I will take a look and get back you after some time. Now I jumped to another work :)

Comment: @barryhunter Still helping people 7 years later :) Thanks for the script. For those that want it, don't forget to grab http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/_database.phps and to upgrade the mysql_* methods toat least mysqli_* methods. Took me 5 minutes. Thanks so much!!!